# Apply a colormap only to unmasked region (excluding the black mask)

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, opencv

I'm still very new to cv2 and python, so please forgive me if this is basic or a duplicate. I've tried searching but to no avail. I have an image, say this [penguin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8OT9.jpg), that I have masked using the `cv2.inRange()` function. I then tried to apply the Viridis colormap to the image, but it applies to everything, including the mask. I want the colormap to *only* apply to the unmasked region to accentuate the subtle differences in value. In essence, I want the lowest value in the unmasked region to be mapped to Viridis' purple, and the highest value in the unmasked region to be the Viridis' yellow, with the values in between linearly mapped.

Here's my attempt and [resulting image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QJqp.jpg). Notice how the masked, previously black region, has been included in the mapping and is now purple. I'm not even sure if it's possible. Maybe a custom colormap is needed?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 

img = cv2.imread('penguin.jpg') #Read in image
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) #Change to HSV

# define range of white color in HSV
lower_white = np.array([0,0,210])
upper_white = np.array([255,255,255])


mask = cv2.inRange(img, lower_white, upper_white) # Create the mask
bitwise_mask = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img,mask=mask) # Apply mask
masked_core = cv2.cvtColor(bitwise_mask, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR) #Change to BGR

#But how do I get it to apply only to unmasked area?
not_desired = cv2.applyColorMap(masked_core, cv2.COLORMAP_VIRIDIS) #Viridis Colormap

#Display and write image
cv2.imwrite('penguin_masked.jpg', not_desired)
cv2.imshow('penguin', not_desired)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to your comment, perhaps this is what you want in Python/OpenCV. My answer is nearly the same except how I compute the grayscale image to be color mapped. I convert your low and high colors to intensity values. Then convert the color image to intensity grayscale. Then stretch your [0,0,210] equivalent intensity to black and your [255,255,255] equivalent intensity (255) to white with all values stretched linearly in between.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 
from skimage.exposure import rescale_intensity

img = cv2.imread('penguin.jpg') #Read in image
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) #Change to HSV

# define range of white color in HSV
lower_white = np.array([0,0,210])
upper_white = np.array([255,255,255])

mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_white, upper_white) # Create the mask

# Y = 0.299 R + 0.587 G + 0.114 B
# convert [0,0,210] to intensity = 0.299*210 = 63
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #Change to gray (intensity)
gray = rescale_intensity(gray, in_range=(63,255), out_range=(0,255)).astype(np.uint8) # linearly stretch 63 to black and 255 to white

colormap = cv2.applyColorMap(gray, cv2.COLORMAP_VIRIDIS) #Viridis Colormap to gray image

img_masked = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask) # Apply mask to img

colormap_masked = cv2.bitwise_and(colormap, colormap, mask=(255-mask)) # Apply inverse mask to colormapped

result = cv2.add(img_masked, colormap_masked) # Merge original and colormapped using mask

#Display and write image
cv2.imwrite('penguin_mask.jpg', mask)
cv2.imwrite('penguin_colormapped2.jpg', colormap)
cv2.imwrite('penguin_result.jpg', result)

cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('colormapped2', colormap)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Mask:

[image]

Color Mapped Image:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the image
- Convert to HSV
- Threshold the HSV using inRange() to make a mask
- Convert the image to grayscale
- Apply the colormap to the grayscale image
- Apply the mask to the input image
- Apply the inverse map to the colormapped image
- Add the two masked images together to for the result
- Save the result

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 

img = cv2.imread('penguin.jpg') #Read in image
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) #Change to HSV

# define range of white color in HSV
lower_white = np.array([0,0,210])
upper_white = np.array([255,255,255])

mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_white, upper_white) # Create the mask
print(mask.shape, np.amax(mask))

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #Change img to GRAY

colormap = cv2.applyColorMap(gray, cv2.COLORMAP_VIRIDIS) #Viridis Colormap to gray image

img_masked = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask) # Apply mask to img

colormap_masked = cv2.bitwise_and(colormap, colormap, mask=(255-mask)) # Apply inverse mask to colormapped

result = cv2.add(img_masked, colormap_masked) # Merge original and colormapped using mask

#Display and write image
cv2.imwrite('penguin_mask.jpg', mask)
cv2.imwrite('penguin_colormapped.jpg', colormap)
cv2.imwrite('penguin_result.jpg', result)

cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('colormapped', colormap)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Mask Image:

[image]

Colormapped Image:

[image]

Result:

[image]

**NOTE: If I have misunderstood and you want the penguin color mapped, then just swap the mask and the inverse mask in the bitwise_and operations.**

Comment: Not quite what I was after, but I think that is because I don't know how to ask the question. I want the color map to use the lower bound [0,0,210] of the `in.Range()` and assign it the color #440154ff, and then assign the upper bound [255,255,255] the color #fde725ff and then the values in between those two points linearly interpolated. Essentially, I want to show the very subtle differences in value using color. Not sure if that makes sense. I've tried to recreate in GIMP but I'm not having much luck. Maybe i'm fundamentally misunderstanding a key concept.

Comment: The inRange result is binary. Includes but not exclusively your [0,0,210] and all colors darker and your [255,255,255] for the brightest. So [0,0,210] is not the only color at black. Do you just want black in your mask to go to  #440154ff and white to go to #fde725ff so that you only have two colors from the color map? If so there are easier ways to do that. Sorry, I am still puzzled what you want. Which image are you trying to color map -- the input or the mask?